# css select a class if parent have a class

Tags: html, css

Can i select somehow a group of elements if a class of the parent changes. Like in these example.
The parent class can be alertStateTrue or alertStateFalse.

```
<div id="parent" class="alertStateTrue">
   <div class="childAlertStateTrue"></div>
   <div class="childAlertStateTrue"></div>
   <div class="childAlertStateFalse"></div>
   <div class="childAlertStateFalse"></div>
</div>

.alertStateTrue .childAlertStateTrue
{
   display: block;
}

.alertStateTrue .childAlertStateFalse
{
   display: none;
}

.alertStateFalse .childAlertStateTrue
{
   display: none;
}

.alertStateFalse .childAlertStateFalse
{
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: Didn't got your question

Comment: @Mr. Alien i add class to the parent, this should hide or show some of the childeren.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can select elements based on their parents:

```
.a .b {}
```

The above rule will select all `.b` elements inside the `.a` ones.

---

### HINT

You can compress your CSS by **grouping** the selectors which have exact rules:

```
.alertStateFalse .childAlertStateFalse,
.alertStateTrue .childAlertStateTrue {
   display: block;
}

.alertStateTrue .childAlertStateFalse,
.alertStateFalse .childAlertStateTrue {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: tried the same thing before, doesn't work. Think i got a typo. Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a parent child relationship in CSS structure, you can do as per NOX answer.

If you want to be a more specific than below structure will help you

Use your #parent div.childAlertStateTrue

This will work fine.